# unclear on reasons why there is a race condition

Tags: go, race-condition

The question concerns the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var counters = map[int]int{}
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func(counters map[int]int, th int) {
            for j := 0; j < 5; j++ {
                counters[th*10+j]++
            }
        }(counters, i)
    }
    fmt.Scanln()
    fmt.Println("counters result", counters)
}
```

Here is the output I get when I run this code with `go run -race race.go`

```
$ go run -race race.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000092150 by goroutine 8:
  runtime.mapaccess1_fast64()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/map_fast64.go:12 +0x0
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/race.go:10 +0x6b

Previous write at 0x00c000092150 by goroutine 7:
  runtime.mapassign_fast64()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/map_fast64.go:92 +0x0
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/race.go:10 +0xaf

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:8 +0x67

Goroutine 7 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:8 +0x67
==================

==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000aa188 by main goroutine:
  reflect.typedmemmove()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/mbarrier.go:177 +0x0
  reflect.copyVal()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/reflect/value.go:1297 +0x7b
  reflect.(*MapIter).Value()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/reflect/value.go:1251 +0x15e
  internal/fmtsort.Sort()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/internal/fmtsort/sort.go:61 +0x259
  fmt.(*pp).printValue()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/fmt/print.go:773 +0x146f
  fmt.(*pp).printArg()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/fmt/print.go:716 +0x2ee
  fmt.(*pp).doPrintln()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/fmt/print.go:1173 +0xad
  fmt.Fprintln()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/fmt/print.go:264 +0x65
  main.main()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/fmt/print.go:274 +0x13c

Previous write at 0x00c0000aa188 by goroutine 10:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/race.go:10 +0xc4

Goroutine 10 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:8 +0x67
==================
counters result map[0:1 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 20:1 21:1 22:1 23:1 24:1 30:1 31:1 32:1 33:1 34:1 40:1 41:1 42:1 43:1 44:1]
Found 2 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

Here is what I can't understand. Why there a race condition at all? Aren't we reading/writing values only one go routine can access? For example routine 0 will modify values only in `counter[0]` through `counters[4]`, routine 1 will modify values only in `counters[10]` through `counters[14]`, routine 2 will  only modify values in `counters[20]` through `counters[24]` and so on. I'm not seeing a race condition here. Feels like I'm missing something. Will someone be able to shed some light on this?

Just an FYI I'm new to go. If you could dumb down the explanation (if it is possible) I would appreciate it.

Comment: One of the specific use cases for `sync.Map` (rather than a regular map and a mutex) is when "multiple goroutines read, write, and overwrite entries for disjoint sets of keys", so it may be worth looking into in cases like this.

Comment: Agree with @hobbs, just keep in mind that `sync.Map` is "untyped" (it operates in `interface{}` values) and it might perform _worse_ than a map protected by a mutex in specific conditions—those which differ form the cases `sync.Map` is optimized for. Hence almost always the rule of thumb when programming is to first implement the most _undersnandable_ code and only then attempt to remove performance bottlenecks, _if any._

Answer (score 4):

That would be true for an array (or a slice), but a map is a complicated data structure which, among others, have the following properties:

- It's free to relocate the elements stored in it in memory at any time it sees fit.
- A map is initially empty, and placing an element in it (what appears as assignment in your case) involves a lot of operations on the map's internals.

Additionally, in a case like yours — incrementing an integer stored in a map — is really a map lookup, increment, and a map store.
The first and the last operations involve lookup by key.
Now consider what happens if one goroutine performs lookup at the same time another goroutine modifies the map's internal state when performing map store.

---

You might want to read up a bit on what is an associative array, and how it's typically implemented.

Answer (score 1):

> Aren't we reading/writing values only one go routine can access?

You already got a great answer from @kostix on that matter: the internals of the map are modified when you add elements to it, so it's not accurate to think that *routine 0 will modify values **only** in `counter[0]` through `counters[4]`*.

But that's not all.

**There's yet another data race issue in your code** that's a bit more subtle and might be very difficult to catch even in tests.

To explore it, let's get rid of the "map internals" issue that @kostix mentioned, by imagining that your code is almost exactly the same, but with one tiny change: instead of using a `map[int]int`, imagine that you're using a `[]int`, initialized to have at least length 56. Something like this:

```
// THERE'S ANOTHER RACE CONDITION HERE.

// var counters = map[int]int{}
var counters = make([]int, 56)
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    // go func(counters map[int]int, th int) {
    go func(counters []int, th int) {
        for j := 0; j < 5; j++ {
            counters[th*10+j]++
        }
    }(counters, i)
}
fmt.Scanln()
fmt.Println("counters result", counters)
```

This is nearly equivalent, but gets rid of the "map internals" issue. The goal is to shift the focus away from "map internals" to show you the second issue.

**There's still a race condition there.** By the way, it's also similar to a race condition that exists in the first attempted solution in another answer you got, that uses a `sync.Mutex` but in a way that is still wrong.

The problem here is that **there's no *happens before* relationship between the operations that change the counters and the operation that reads from it**.

The `fmt.Scanln()` doesn't help: even though it allows you to introduce an arbitrary time delay between the code right before it (i.e., when the `for` loop launches the goroutines) and the code right after it (i.e., the `fmt.Println()`) — so that you could think *"Ok, I'm just gonna wait 'a reasonably long amount of time' before pressing Enter"*, that doesn't eliminate the race condition.

The race condition here arises from the fact that "passage of time" (i.e., you waiting to hit Enter) does not establish a *happens-before* relationship between the writes to `counters` and the reads from it.

This notion of *happens-before* is absolutely fundamental for avoiding data races: you can only guarantee the absence of a data race if you can guarantee the existence of a happens-before relationship between 2 operations.

Like I mentioned, "passage of time" doesn't establish a "happens before". To establish it, you could use one of many alternatives, including primitives in the `sync` or `atomic` packages, or channels, etc.

While I'd probably suggest focusing on studying channels, and then the `sync` package (`sync.Mutex`, `sync.WaitGroup`, etc), and maybe only after all that the `atomic` package, if you do want to read more about this idea of *happens before* from the authoritative source, here's the link: https://golang.org/ref/mem . But be warned that it's a nasty can of worms.

Hopefully these comments here help you see why it's absolutely fundamental to follow the standard patterns for concurrency in Go. Things can be way more subtle than at first sight.

And to conclude, a quote from The Go Memory Model link I shared above:

> *If you must read the rest of this document to understand the behavior of your program, you are being too clever.*
>
> *Don't be clever.*

---

EDIT: for completion, here's how you could solve the problem.

There are 2 parts to the solution: (1) make sure that there's no concurrent modifications to the map; (2) make sure that there's a happens-before between all the changes to the map and the read.

For (1), you can use a `sync.Mutex`. Lock it before writing, unlock it after the write.

For (2), you need to ensure that the main goroutine can only get to the `fmt.Println()` after all the modifications are done. And remember: here, *after* doesn't mean *"at a later point in time"*, but it specifically means that a happens-before relationship must be established. The 2 common patterns to solve this are to use a channel or a `sync.WaitGroup`. The WaitGroup solution is probably easier to reason about here, so that's what I'd use.

```
var mu sync.Mutex                 // (A)
var wg sync.WaitGroup             // (A)

var counters = map[int]int{}

wg.Add(5)                         // (B)

for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    go func(counters map[int]int, th int) {
        for j := 0; j < 5; j++ {
            mu.Lock()             // (C)
            counters[th*10+j]++
            mu.Unlock()           // (C)
        }
        wg.Done()                 // (D)
    }(counters, i)
} 
wg.Wait()                         // (E)
fmt.Scanln()
fmt.Println("counters result", counters)
```

(A) You don't need to initialize either the Mutex nor the WaitGroup, since their zero values are ready to use. Also, you don't need to make them pointers to anything.

(B) You `.Add(5)` to the `WaitGroup`'s counter, meaning that it will have to wait for 5 `.Done()` signals before proceeding if you `.Wait()` on it. The number 5 here is because you're launching 5 goroutines, and you need to establish happens-before relationships between the changes made on all of them and the main goroutine's `fmt.Println()`.

(C) You `.Lock()` and `.Unlock()` the `Mutex` around modifications to the `map`, to ensure that they are not done concurrently.

(D) Just before each goroutine terminates, you call `wg.Done()`, which decrements the `WaitGroup`'s internal counter.

(E) Finally, you `wg.Wait()`. This function blocks until the `wg`'s counter reaches 0. And here's the super important piece: the `WaitGroup` establishes a happens-before relationship between the calls to `wg.Done()` and the return of the `wg.Wait()` call. In other words, from a memory consistency perspective, the main goroutine is guaranteed to see all the changes performed to the map by all the goroutines!

AND FINALLY you can run that code with `-race` and be happy!

For you to explore further: instead of `map + sync.Mutex`, you could replace that with just `sync.Map`. But the `sync.WaitGroup` would still be necessary. Try to write a solution using that, it might be a nice exercise.

Comment: Good answer ! I see now why my first example is still wrong. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @kostix answer. You've to know that multiple goroutines should not access (write/read) to the same ressource at a given time.
So, in your implementation you may easly be in the case that multiple goroutines are updating (reading/writing) concurrently the same ressource (which is your map) at the same time.

What should happen ? Which value should be in this given map key ? This a what called [`race condition`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Here is some potential fixes to your code:

Using [`Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var counters = map[int]int{}
    var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go func(counters map[int]int, th int) {
            for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
                mutex.Lock()  // Lock the access to the map
                counters[th*10+j]++
                mutex.Unlock() // Release the access
            }
        }(counters, i)
    }
    fmt.Scanln()
    fmt.Println("counters result", counters)
}
```

Output:

```
counters result map[0:1 1:1 2:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 20:1 21:1 22:1]
```

Using [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/src/sync/map.go):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var counters sync.Map
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go func(th int) {
            for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
                if result, ok := counters.Load(th*10 + j); ok {
                    value := result.(int) + 1
                    counters.Store(th*10+j, value+1)
                } else {
                    counters.Store(th*10+j, 1)
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }
    fmt.Scanln()
    counters.Range(func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        fmt.Println("key:", k, ", value:", v)
        return true
    })
}
```

Output:

```
key: 21 , value: 1
key: 10 , value: 1
key: 11 , value: 1
key: 0 , value: 1
key: 1 , value: 1
key: 20 , value: 1
key: 2 , value: 1
key: 22 , value: 1
key: 12 , value: 1
```

Comment: There's still a race condition on the first snippet, the one using a `sync.Mutex`: if you don't lock the mutex before reading the counters (i.e., the `fmt.Println(...)` line), there's no guarantee that any of the updates to the counters will be visible to the main goroutine, thus to the `fmt.Println(...)` function.

Comment: @BrunoReis after reading your answer i know now why the first attempt still wrong even with `mutex`. I didn't want to introduce `channels` in my attemps because it'll change the intial structure of the functions and how they're called. But you're totally right. Thanks for your comment.